# wordpress error: http raw post data does not exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting this error [error: http raw post data does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fYTN.png) on my wordpress website everywhere, on wordpress dashboard and on website. website is still working but this error is on top of every page. I am running php 7.4.7 and WordPress 5.5.8. Can someone help with this please?

Comment: http_raw_post_data was removed in PHP 7.0. You're going to have to find where it's used. If you're using Linux or Mac, try `grep -R http_raw_post_data *` from the root of Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

your PHP version does not support http_raw_post_data
so you must disable plugin or template that use http_raw_post_data or temporarily disable "Debug Mode" in wp-config.php